# Как зашифровать/расшифровать данные на golang/javascript передаваемые по Websocket протоколу?

Tags: golang, ssl, безопасность

Как зашифровать/расшифровать данные на golang/javascript передаваемые по Websocket протоколу?
Использую code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket

Comment: Пожалуйста покажите, как Вы организовываете подключение в Go. Собственно как в устаревшем (а может быть и точно таком же - потому как все code.google.com/p/go.net/... переехали на golang.org/x/net/... и изменилось ли что-то с момента переезда) я не знаю. Но вот например референс собственно про шифрование: [рас](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#wss). А вот [здесь](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket#Config) в документации есть графа `TlsConfig *tls.Config`. Я надеюсь это - то что нужно.

Comment: Вот [пример](http://play.golang.org/p/FM79CQOQT1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я рекомендую вам отказаться от `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket`, т.к. он сильно устарел. Если использовать `github.com/gorilla/websocket`, как это делают большинство, то тогда ничего зашифровывать/расшифровывать не надо, просто используете `wss://` вместо `ws://`, и все:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func main() {
    ws, _, _ := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("wss://echo.websocket.org", nil)
    ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Hello!"))
    _, resp, _ := ws.ReadMessage()
    log.Println("response: " + string(resp))
    return
}
```